# Adding a language to Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7

I have been having an issue with a PDF and some text not being recognized.

I had a suggestion that I add the language to my computer and looking into it I have not been able to find a concrete answer on how to do that.

The language is Burmese, I have Windows 7 Enterprise. I need to add it to my computer so my visual studios will recognize it and I can insert the text into a PDF.

Where would I find the language pack download and if it is on my computer and I push it into our test environment would it break when it is no longer on my computer or would it being compiled already prevent the text from breaking?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try with few Fonts,
2. You can find Available Language packs from Microsoft [here](http://[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14236][1])
3. Search for Language packs Developed by Third Party, [here](http://www.mymyanmar.net/)